# Eliminate duplicate from a Multi-Line string

Tags: vb.net

I have a text-box control called `Textbox1` which contains the following items (in a Multi-line string):

```
22,23
57,58
20,21
51,52
57,58
20,21
21,22
25,26
35,36
41,42
50,51
22,23
23,24
37,38
44,45
45,46
67,68
72,73
78,79
```

How do I remove 2-digit duplicates? Instead of 20,21, it does not appear twice and once. If the combination of 2 numbers still exists in another line, then this combination appears once. and so on.

Comment: There are multiple approaches, one I suggest using a Dictionary. Add each line to a key of a Dictionary only if not Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ContainsKey(TKey).

Comment: Does the order matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(New String() {vbCrLf, vbCr, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Dim repeatedElement As String = ""

    'First have to sort array
    System.Array.Sort(lines)

    For Each Line As String In lines
        If Not (String.Compare(Line, repeatedElement) = 0) Then
            TextBox2.Text += Line & vbCrLf
        End If

        repeatedElement = Line
    Next
End Sub
```

Here textBox1 is for source text and textBox2 is for result.

Comment: Thanks, the code is good as saving both values. and with duplicates but without.